# Change background based on device orientation

Tags: android

How can I change the background color based on the device orientation in an Android app?

If the device is vertical (portrait), change to yellow;
if it is horizontal (landscape), change to green.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a method from Activity that is called:
getRequestedOrientation()

So you can do:

```
if (getRequestedOrientation() == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        dLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bpblack));
    } else {
        dLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bpBlue));
    }
```

Put this on yout Activity's onCreate and every time you change your orientation, onCreate will be called again and your background will change it's color.

Good luck.

Comment: it did not work, when i change my device orientation the app stops, here my code:
 `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Ll=(LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.layo);
        txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        if (getRequestedOrientation() == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            Ll.setBackgroundColor((Color.GREEN));
        } else {
            Ll.setBackgroundColor((Color.BLACK));
        }`